# NGRX set timer between two actions

Tags: angular, redux, timer, ngrx

I am using Angular and NGRX, I want to set a timer between two actions, when the first action triggers the timer should start and with the second action it should be stopped. I should be able to save the timer in a global variable or in my state as I will be sending this to the database later.
The following is a good example what I want to achieve but I don't know to to this using ngrx.
Mine is incrementing so it's not a stopwatch.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/timer-with-pause?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**State**

```
 export type MainContentState = 'empty' | IMainContent;
    
    export interface IMainContent {
        insert: boolean;
        modified: boolean;
        connectionOK: boolean;
        sessionDuration: any;
        interval: any;
    }
```

**Reducer**

```
  export function mainContentReducer(state: MainContentState = 'empty', action: MainReducerActions): MainContentState {
            let interval;
            let timer = 0;
            switch (action.type) {
              case START_SESSION_TIMER: {
                startSessionTimer(interval, timer);   
                // also tried this    startSessionTimer(state.interval, state.sessionDuration); 
                if (state === 'empty') {
                    return state;
                }
                return { ...state, sessionDuration: timer };
    
            }
              case STOP_SESSION_TIMER: {
                stopSessionTimer(interval, timer);
                // also tried this    stopSessionTimer(state.interval, state.sessionDuration);
                if (state === 'empty') {
                    return state;
                }
                return { ...state, sessionDuration: timer };
    
            }
                return state;
    }
 }



    function startSessionTimer(interval: any, timer: any) {
        debugger
         interval = setInterval(() => {
                timer++;
          }, 1000);
    
    }
    

    function stopSessionTimer( interval: any) {
        debugger
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
```

Comment: What is the relation between the start and finish actions and where are they called from?

Comment: The first action is called in the @effect after getting, so after retrieving data (Menu's) The START_SESSION_TIMER is dispatched. The second action is called from the app.component.ts, this action is triggered when the iFrame (Desktop c++ app) in my application is fully loaded. I want to save the number of seconds it takes to load the iframe each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be setting timers or doing anything else aside from setting state inside your reducers.

A different approach would be:

**State**

2 properties in your state = `sessionStartTime` & `sessionEndTime` of type `Date`

**Actions**

- `SET_SESSION_START_TIME` & `SET_SESSION_END_TIME`. Both take a `Date` as their payload, and set the corresponding properties in the state via the reducer. These are dispatched from the same places you dispatch your existing equivalent actions.
- `SAVE_SESSION_DURATION` & `SAVE_SESSION_DURATION_SUCCEEDED` which have no payload. The first one is dispatched when you want to save the duration to the DB, the second one when that operation succeeds.

**Effect**

An effect which saves the session duration to the DB:

```
 saveSessionDuration$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType("SAVE_SESSION_DURATION"),
      withLatestFrom(
        this.store$.select(selectSessionStartTime),
        this.store$.select(selectSessionEndTime)
      ),
      switchMap(([startTime, endTime]) =>
        this.dbService
          .saveSessionDuration(endTime - startTime)
          .pipe(map(() => ({ type: "SAVE_SESSION_DURATION_SUCCEEDED" })))
      // TODO handle errors
      )
    )
  );
```